# How can I add a unique function to each item in a loop based on the ID of the item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop, event-handling

I have a few html `<div>` elements that each have another `<div>` nested in them. The nested element is responsible for the CSS, and the outer element is responsible for the JavaScript. (The outer `<div>` element is necessary because the nested element would have holes in its hitbox if it was responsible for detecting clicks.)

Anyways, to aid my explanation, here's my code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-wrapper');
  [...buttons].forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var target = this.children[0]
    target.classList.toggle('toggled')
    console.log(target)
    // code dependant on the value of this
  }))
};
```

```css
/* css for each button has been removed because I don't want to release them yet...*/

body {
  margin: 5%;
  display: flex;
  -moz-column-gap: 5%;
  column-gap: 5%;
  row-gap: 5%;
}

.icon-wrapper {
  height: 8vmin;
  width: 8vmin;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* extra code for visablility */
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <div id="menu-icon"></div>
</div>
<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <div id="full-screen-icon"></div>
</div>
<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <div id="tab-icon"></div>
</div>
<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <div id="volume-icon"></div>
</div>
<iframe class="windowed" id="iframe" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="https://www.heavensgate.com/">
</iframe>
```

Now on to the actual specifics! As you can see, each button will have a unique function. My problem is that I can't assign a unique function to each event listener based on the element it's targeting. For example, when the second icon wrapper which contains the full screen button `<div>` is clicked, the `<iframe>` element will request full screen. But when the third button is clicked, the `<iframe>` will open in a new tab. Basically, I want each iteration of the `forEach` loop to have a different function. Finally, if possible, I also want the unique function to be based on the Id of the nested element, and not the index of the loop/array, so I can reorder the elements without it breaking.

I hope I got the point across in this post, but if you need me to elaborate on anything, please ask.

Edit: Unless they post a stand-alone answer, check the comments for what Barmar said, it seems to be what I was after.

Comment: Where do these unique functions come from? How does it know which function goes with each iteration?

Comment: You have no CSS for `.toggled`. What is clicking on the button supposed to do?

Comment: Do you really need unique functions? You could add classes or data attributes to the elements, and the function can check these to determine what it should do for the specific element you click on.

Comment: If you want it to be based on the ID of the element, you could have an object or Map that maps IDs to functions.

Comment: You could just use a `switch` statement: `switch(target.id)`

Comment: @Barmar the toggled class is included in the main code, all that matters here is that the element gets the class when the corresponding button is pressed. for the unique functions, it doesn't matter what any of them would do, just that I could make one for each button. also, it would seem switch is exactly what I'm after. if you'd like to add an answer in the comments, I can mark this question as answered.

Comment: What's the point of making an executable snippet if it doesn't actually do anything relevant to the question? Anyway, I described a number of ways you can do what you want. Pick one.

Comment: `const functions = {"menu-icon": function() { ... }, "full-screen-icon": function() { ... }, ...}`. Then use `button.addEventListener("click", functions[target.id])`

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer that I got in the comments from @Barmar

"You could just use a `switch` statement: `switch(target.id)`"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object to associate each id with a function to execute on click (as also mentioned by Barmar).

Also note that if you use `document.querySelectorAll`, you can directly call `forEach` without converting the result to an array first.

```js
const fns = {
    "menu-icon"() {
        console.log('menu icon clicked');
    },
    "full-screen-icon"() {
        console.log('full screen icon clicked');
    }
    // ...
};
document.querySelectorAll('.icon-wrapper').forEach(wrapper =>
    wrapper.addEventListener('click', fns[wrapper.firstElementChild.id]));
```